# How to simulate the printing of object like in C# Interactive Console?

Tags: c#, c#-interactive

An example:

[image]

If we type `scoreDir` in the C# Console, its content is pretty printed, i.e. the definition of the object, its length and its data.

I would like to simulate this printing with a **built-in .NET method**, e.g. `ToString()`. However, `ToString()` doesn't work, as showed. "Simulate" means I can generate the same printed string, but store it in a variable. Microsoft must have used some function to print such object; it's best to just re-use the function (no re-inventing the wheels).

Comment: There is as far as I know nothing built into .NET that does this for you. Likely this is built into the interactive console application instead.

Comment: though not as nice as what the interactive console does (or even as nice as a `record.ToString()`) I often find myself doing a call to `JsonSerializer.Serialize(myObject)` since the resulting JSON is more usable than out-of-the-box `.ToString()` in most cases.

Comment: There are several restrictions to serialize a ConcurrentDictionary, from bugs to other problems that you can check in S.O. or Google, so I will answer about Newtonsoft and .NET 6.0, check the note on my answer

Comment: @DCAggie JsonSerializer.Serialize won't work in this case

Comment: Add [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting/4.1.0-1.final), generate the string with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.Hosting.CSharpObjectFormatter.Instance.FormatObject(scoredir);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to @[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in the comment section.

In Visual Studio, after installing the Nuget package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting`, the static function `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.Hosting.CSharpObjectFormatter.Instance.FormatObject()` can be used to mimic the same output as C# Interactive Console.

Here is the code that works:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scoreDir = new ConcurrentDictionary<(int, int), (double, int)>();
            scoreDir.TryAdd((1, 2), (0.9, 3));
            var res = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.Hosting.CSharpObjectFormatter.Instance.FormatObject(scoreDir);
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no such build tool for this but you can convert it to Json. The problem with your example that is not so easy for a ConcurrentDictionary.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
This only will work for `Newtonsoft` and `.NET 6.0` since `System.Text.Json` does not provide a cast for serialize to JSON `ConcurrentDictionary` and this also don't work for `Newtonsoft` in `.NET Framework`

**How to Serialize to JSON string a ConcurrentDictionary?**

Import `Newtonsoft.Json` from Nugget

Add `using Newtonsoft.Json;` to the references in the head of the file

```
ConcurrentDictionary<(int,int), (double,int)> scoreDir = new ConcurrentDictionary<(int,int), (double,int)>();
scoreDir.TryAdd((1,2),(0.9,3));
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoreDir);
Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

Returns:

> {"(1, 2)":{"Item1":0.9,"Item2":3}}

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XzHHoN